# How do you create a custom Kivymd MDDialog which will popup GridLayout or any other widget insted of default

Tags: python, kivy

Am creating a calling app and i need on_release button to popup keypads as in my attachment.
[I need to create something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thtbI.png)

Comment: Looks like you can [content_cls](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/dialog/index.html#kivymd.uix.dialog.MDDialog.content_cls) to use any class you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what i deed.

## main.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Content(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kpads = self.ids.kpads
        for i in range(1, 13):
            btn = Button(text=str(i))
            self.kpads.add_widget(btn)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None


    def show_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                type="custom",
                size_hint=(.7, .6),
                content_cls=Content())

        self.dialog.open()


MainApp().run()
```

## main.kv

```
<Content>:
    GridLayout:
        id: kpads
        cols: 3

FloatLayout:
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_dialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Popup instead of MDDialog

```
    if not self.dialog:
        # self.dialog = MDDialog(
        #     type="custom",
        #     size_hint=(.7, .6),
        #     content_cls=Content())

        self.dialog = Popup(
            title="Type Title Here",
            size_hint=(.7, .6),
            content=Content())

    self.dialog.open()
```